# Trying to Adding Select Dropdown in ANT D table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in react and trying to implement dropdown inside table cell using Ant [link](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell) UI framework.

I have tried to render Dropdown component inside `renderCell` function but I am stuck.

My implementation: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-fast-ngf2s)

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please confirm that, do you need to render drop down as default or you need it when you click on table cell for editing.

Comment: true I need drop down when first time or as default .

Comment: I have updated the answer and If it works for you then please accept my answer. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, I think you want to have dropdown when you click on a table cell to do editing, correct me if I am wrong?

In your code, I have seen that instead of `select` or `Dropdown` component you have used `input`.

I have forked your sandbox which you have provided and updated the code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-shamir-lxvk3

This is what I have done and it's working.

```
renderCell = form => {
    this.form = form;
    const { children, dataIndex, record, title } = this.props;
    const { editing } = this.state;
    const menu = (
      <Menu>
        <Menu.Item key="1">1st menu item</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="2">2nd menu item</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="3">3rd menu item</Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    );
    return editing ? (
      <Form.Item style={{ margin: 0 }}>
        {form.getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: `${title} is required.`
            }
          ],
          initialValue: record[dataIndex]
        })(
          <Dropdown overlay={menu}>
            <span style={{ userSelect: "none" }}>hover on Me</span>
          </Dropdown>
        )}
      </Form.Item>
    ) : (
      <div className="editable-cell-value-wrap" style={{ paddingRight: 24 }} onClick={this.toggleEdit}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

If you want Droupdown to be rendered as default then add Dropdown component in else condition

> Note: Please hover on the text.

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-haze-k387u

```
renderCell = form => {
    this.form = form;
    const { children, dataIndex, record, title } = this.props;
    const { editing } = this.state;
    const menu = (
      <Menu>
        <Menu.Item key="1">1st menu item</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="2">2nd menu item</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="3">3rd menu item</Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    );
    return editing ? (
      <Form.Item style={{ margin: 0 }}>
        {form.getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: `${title} is required.`
            }
          ],
          initialValue: record[dataIndex]
        })(<Input ref={node => (this.input = node)} onPressEnter={this.save} onBlur={this.save} />)}
      </Form.Item>
    ) : (
      <div className="editable-cell-value-wrap" style={{ paddingRight: 24 }} onClick={this.toggleEdit}>
        <Dropdown overlay={menu}>
          <span style={{ userSelect: "none" }}>{children}</span>
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    );
  };
```